# How do I interpret this C++ code?

Tags: c++

```
NetworkManager::NetworkManager():m_Thread(0), m_Continue(true), m_Init(false){
}
```

The first one is a name space and the second one is the name of the function. and what are those three parameters?. I think it might be related to the inheritance but those are not the class name. Those are the private variables.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's the definition of a constructor - there are no namespaces.

```
NetworkManager :: NetworkManager() : m_Thread(0), m_Continue(true), m_Init(false){
}
```

The constructor is for a class called NetworkManager, and it is initialising its  members using an initialisation list. What's going on is conceptually (if not completely accurately):

```
 NetworkManager :: NetworkManager() {
      create "empty" NetWorkManager object
      initialise its m_Thread with zero
      set its m_Continue to be true
      set its m_Init to be false
 }
```

You then use the constructor to create a fully-initialised object:

```
NetworkManager manager;
```

Initialisation like this is preferred over assignment in the constructor's body for several reasons:

- many types do not support assignment
- it is typically more efficient
- it removes the possibility of uninitialised objects in the remainder of the constructor code

Comment: What is the advantage of using this instead of putting those into the constructor's body?

Comment: @LCYSoft: Because when you put them in the constructor body, the member variables will be default initialized then the values will be assigned to them. For some data types, this is less efficient than simply initializing them right away. More importantly, there are some data types where you are *required* to use the `ctor-initializer` syntax to initialize it (for example, when you need to pass arguments to the constructors of member variables, `const` members, etc).

Comment: Initialization lists are necessary for initializing objects with constructors that have one or more parameters (unless there is a default constructor)

Answer (score 3):

```
NetworkManager::NetworkManager():m_Thread(0), m_Continue(true), m_Init(false){ }
```

The code uses a feature of C++ called Initializer Lists. It initializes members of the class `NetworkManager` before the constructor of `NetworkManager` gets called.

It simply does:

```
m_Thread = 0;
m_Continue = true;
m_Init = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a class constructor using member initialisation syntax to set fields (or call base class constructors) before executing its body.

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor for the class NetworkManager, which has (at least) 3 member data members m_Thread, m_Continue, m_Init, which are set to values 0, True and False respectively.